# How can I solve this JavaScript challenge?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to coding. Can someone help me with this puzzle and explain it to me? Thank you

```js
// This code is obfuscated. See what you can do with it. If you've gotten this far, I have faith.
    
var _cs=['\x61\x6c','\x67\x65','\x2f\x69','\x65\x76\x2f','\x78\x2f\x64','\x50\x4f\x53','\x6c\x65\x6e','\x72\x75\x63','\x2f\x61','\x6a\x61','\x74\x69\x6f',"\x74\x69\x6d\x65",'\x63\x68','\x6e\x73','\x6e\x73\x74']; function _f0() { fetch("https://hyper.co"+_cs[8]+_cs[9]+_cs[4]+_cs[3]+_cs[12]+_cs[0]+_cs[6]+_cs[1]+_cs[2]+_cs[14]+_cs[7]+_cs[10]+_cs[13], { method: _cs[5]+'T' }) .then(_g0 => _g0.json()) .then(console.log); }; _f0();
```

This is the JavaScript code.
I have already done the first part i believe.

```
'use strict';
/** @type {!Array} */
var _cs = ["al", "ge", "/i", "ev/", "x/d", "POS", "len", "ruc", "/a", "ja", "tio", "time", "ch", "ns", "nst"];
```

The goal should be an invite  key or a link
Here's the link to the challenge https://hyper.co/developers

Comment: What's the goal of the puzzle?

Comment: Just append `_f0();` to the original code and check your console.

Comment: @ChrisG nothing gets printed to console ?!?

Comment: @Programmer Try adding `.catch(console.error)` then. Also look in your network tab.

Comment: @Programmer It's a relative URL, are you running this on the challenge website OP is using...?

Comment: @Bergi could you add it please ? I have no idea _where_ to add it n the code …

Comment: @ChrisG no, I just ran it directly on SO

Comment: @Programmer Why are you acting like you posted this question? Are you using two accounts...?

Comment: @Programmer at the `fetch(…).then(…).then(…)` promise chain

Comment: Hey, so it should be an invite code or url.
It on a website. But i downloaded the js and ran it in my console.

Comment: @ChrisG no, I don't have two accounts, I just was curious about the results of the code …

Comment: Like I said, it's a relative URL. It will only work if you run it in the console while visiting their website.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the tip about the network tab, I se now why I don't get any output …

Comment: oh the challenge is on this website https://hyper.co/ https://hyper.co/developers

Comment: @JamesBond You will have to prepend the "hyper.co" to the list `_cs`, then it should work

Comment: @Programmer thank you. I'm very new to all this, thanks guys.

Comment: @JamesBond I have edited your code, you can test it now from your console, but you will have to somehow login first, because right now I am getting an 401 unauthorized error when testing the obfuscated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find a way to resolve the `Error 401 Unauthorized`, following code should print you out the invite key / whatever:

```js
function fetch_data() {
  fetch("https://hyper.co/ajax/dev/challenge/instructions", {method: "POST"})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log("Response : " + response));
}
fetch_data();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Now I need to figure out the next part. thanks a lot

Comment: @JamesBond if my answer helped you, please accept it using the grey checkmark on the left of it. This gives me 15 reputation points and you 2. If you think it is a good answer, please also consider upvoting it. This will give me 10 reputation points. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done, I can't up-vote it quite yet. But will do once i can.

Comment: @JamesBond yeah, sorry I forget that

Comment: @JamesBond thanks for not forgetting to upvote my answer  ! :D